# Code crashes on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, crash

Every time I run this code, it crashes , I tried all that I can, but I just  don't know which part is crashing and it's not telling me why. I need  it to look through every cell until its respective amount and put into the current sheet.

Is there any advice or see anything that might help?

```
Sub bringbookstogether()

Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Set currentsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

'assigns the number to start with
Dim a, b, c, d As Integer

a = 4
b = 6
c = 3
d = 1

Dim wsheet As Worksheet
Set wsheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(c)

Dim wbook As Workbook

'assigns workbook numbers
If (d = 1) Then
    Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
Else

    If (d = 2) Then
        Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 2nd.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)
    Else

        If (d = 3) Then
            Set wbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 3rd.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)

        End If
    End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'End if it's done with all the workbooks

Do Until (d = 4)

    'Looks for the sheet that has the same name

    Do Until (c = 53)
        If (wsheet.Name = currentsheet.Name) Then

            'Ends in row 99
            Do Until (b = 99)

                'Ends in Column 52
                Do Until (a = 52)

                    currentsheet.Cells(b, a) = currentsheet.Cells(b, a) + Workbooks(d).Sheets(c).Cells(b, a)

                    a = a + 1
                Loop

                b = b + 1
            Loop

        End If
    Loop

    d = d + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: With that many nested loops, please indent your code properly so we can make better sense of it.  Hard to interpret the way it's all left-aligned.

Comment: I wonder why, you have **Only** ~1,091,376 cycles inside your 4 x `Do Until` loops, when each time you access the `Cells` object.

Comment: I am assuming it's the cycles that's crashing it. How do I fix it?

Comment: @MaxAttack102 you need to explain to us better what you are trying to achieve with this code, and what exactly does each of the 4 loops ? perhaps we can offer a solution with a few less

Comment: It's supposed to be taking numbers from multiple charts from three different workbooks on Excel and putting it into one main worksheet in a different workbook, while adding all the numbers from each chart. All the worksheets are similarly named and formatted.

Comment: 1.091.376 potential cycles to add some values together... Maybe not use loops? Have a look at [Ozgrid's article on wrong loops](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm), at Chip Pearson's [article about Arrays and Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) and at [Ozgrid's lesson on avoiding loops](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/free-training/ExcelVBA1/excelvba1lesson11.htm).
Then reconsider your solution, and conclude you want to use something else.

Comment: its not crashing, but taking 2 hours to complete.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what your script does:

1. It sets a number for variable `d`. Based on this one it opens a workbook.
2. Next, it uses variable `c` to start looping at a specific worksheet until it finds the Sheet in the opened workbook that has the same name as the sheet that is active when the macro starts (`Set currentsheet = Application.ActiveSheet`)
3. It sets variable `a` to decide from which Column to 52 it must copy.
4. It sets variable `b` to decide from which Row to 99 it must copy.

Thus, based on this `a,b,c,d` you find 1 worksheet, in 1 workbook and you copy 1 range to the currentsheet. This basically means 1 operation, yet with your loops you make it a potential million operations. Hence the comment section and the incredibly slow performance.

This script does the exact same thing as yours without any loops:

```
Sub bringbookstogether()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim currentsheet As Worksheet
Dim wbook As Workbook
Dim wsheet As Worksheet

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer

Dim fName As String

a = 1 'Only for the starting column! Can't exceed 52
b = 1 'Only for the starting row! Cant' exceed 99
      'I got rid of c, we don't need it.
d = 4 'Not needed to loop. Your loop on d was obsolete.

Set currentsheet = Application.ActiveSheet

'Open the workbook:
Select Case d 'No need for a lot of nested If statements.
    Case 1:
        fName = "C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 1st.xlsm"
    Case 2:
        fName = "C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 2nd.xlsm"
    Case 3:
        fName = "C:\Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet 3rd.xlsm"
        'You might want to consider renaming the files "MaintPrep Sheet 1.xlsm", "MaintPrep Sheet 2.xlsm", etc.
        'In that case you could just do: fName = "C:Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet " & d & ".xlsm" and omit the whole Select.
    Case 4:
        fName = "C:\temp\test.xlsx"
End Select

Set wbook = Workbooks.Open(fName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)

On Error Resume Next 'To avoid subscript out of range error if the same named sheet doesn't exist
    Set wsheet = wbook.Worksheets(currentsheet.Name)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not wsheet Is Nothing Then 'Check if we have the sheet with the same name
    With currentsheet 'Copy range row set in a, column set in a to row 99 and column 52 as per sample loop.
        wsheet.Range(wsheet.Cells(b, a), wsheet.Cells(99, 52)).Copy
        .Range(.Cells(b, a), .Cells(99, 52)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
    End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You'll see that this executes a few hundred (!!!) times faster than the posted script.

**Edit:** 
To loop over each worksheet that is in the ActiveWorkbook and each corresponding sheet in the workbooks, I suggest changing the workbook names from "1st", "2nd", "3rd" etc. to simply 1, 2, 3, 4.

Then:
 - get rid of the `d = 1` line
 - get rid of `c` altogether
 - get rid of the whole `Select Case` block above.
 - Replace the part from `Set wbook = ...` until the last `end if` with the code below:

```
For d = 1 to 4
    fName = "C:Users\mminchuk\Documents\Updated MaintPrep Sheets\MaintPrep Sheet " & d & ".xlsm"
    Set wbook = Workbooks.Open(fName, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways)

    For Each currentSheet in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next 'To avoid subscript out of range error if the same named sheet doesn't exist
        Set wsheet = wbook.Worksheets(currentsheet.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wsheet Is Nothing Then 'Check if we have the sheet with the same name
        With currentsheet 'Copy range row set in a, column set in a to row 99 and column 52 as per sample loop.
            wsheet.Range(wsheet.Cells(b, a), wsheet.Cells(99, 52)).Copy
            .Range(.Cells(b, a), .Cells(99, 52)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd
        End With
    End If
    Next currentSheet
Next d
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, but now it's telling me copy area and paste area are not the same size,why would that occur. It claims that the problem is in
`.Range(.Cells(b, a), .Cells(99, 52)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationAdd`

Comment: I tried to change a and b directly to 1, just to see if it changes the error, but the error still appears

Comment: Any merged cells in either of the ranges? They're the work of satan, so get rid of them. You could do a `ws.cells.unmerge` (or whatever the exact statement is) to ensure there aren't any.

Comment: Sadly, there are. I was just given a template, that's why I had a and b equal to specific numbers, so I wouldn't have to change it

Comment: OK, I got it to work by changing the number it starts on, but it's just taking from sheet 3 and not all 3 sheets

Comment: Just get rid of them altogether if that's an option. Otherwise come up with an algorithm to store all merged range addresses in a string array, unmerge everything, do the copy as above and afterwards merge them again by looping over that string array. It will still be loads faster than what was there before. - Regarding only taking one sheet: That's also what your own loop did. You could do `For each currentSheet in ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` and at the end `Next currentSheet` to get them all. That would be the only loop in there.

Comment: I just realized I said sheets. I am sorry. I meant books

Comment: As for the merged situation. Does it make slower that, I start in a specific cell?

Comment: See edit: I created the loop to open workbook 1-4, and check for each sheet in the macro workbook if one with the same name exists in the openened workbook, then do the copy. You should still get rid of merged cells. The cell in which you "start" is not relevant with my answer, since you do the whole copy of all the cells in a single operation.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you. Also thanks for the articles, I'll definitely keep the loop situation in mind next time I write a code